# Can't remember book/title about a young boy who lost his memory

Tags: story-identification

So the beginning, if I can remember right, starts off in a dark alley filled city. Many people were poor, starving, etc. I think there was this monster (like a huge Tremor worm?) that was attacking this city or something.

Idk, I can't remember much after this but I do know that at one point in the story magic gets involved in some way. I think he lost his memory or something. In order to get his memory back, he has to kind of break this huge mental wall of ice in his mind. (or maybe it's just a blue barrier?) I can't remember.

At some point he ends up with (adult?) companions who try to help him with this barrier? They also live in some kind of weird castle-like building or something? Not sure about the exterior but the interior reminded me of an old stone building.

Also, I'm fairly sure this boy was quite young, perhaps 12-15?

Vague but possible memories:
 Has to go to some kind of "ball" or dance/party
 Dragons lightly mentioned later in the story or in other books.
Book cover was dark and possibly blue/black

I read it anywhere from the year 2009-2011

Any info on this would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you recall any other details? For example, was this set in a technologically advanced society, or more of a medieval world?

Comment: I believe it was much more medieval, as I don't recall much, if any, technology being mentioned. I also don't remember a whole lot of battle-based scenes or conflict.

Comment: Well, this should be easy enough for someone who has read it, in any case.

Comment: Any chance it could be [The Magic Thief?](https://www.amazon.com/Magic-Thief-Sarah-Prineas/dp/006137590X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1472373512&sr=8-1&keywords=magic+thief) It seems a long shot, since the memory loss is near the end of one of the later books. But the time frame is right, and a number of other details match.